# Dishwasher won't drain between cycles but will empty using cancel button

Tags: dishwasher

I can't get my whirlpool dishwasher to empty between cycles,,,I did change the control board and it didn't work,,it will empty with the cancel button, I do not have a disposal I cleaned out the bottom and cleaned the check valve,

Comment: If you want any hope on this one, you should add whatever pictures and all of the troubleshooting information you have so far as well as the exact model of the dishwasher and link to the repair manual if you can find it.  You might want to check exactly what if anything is wired between the control board and drain solenoid and drain pump.

Comment: Did you contact Whirlpool to arrange service.

Comment: @r13 based on the info given, that is about all we can offer in the way of advice, but let's give the OP a chance to [edit] more detail into her post before we make that the final offer. :)

Comment: @FreeMan Sorry, I don't understand your message. I didn't vote to close this post in anticipation the OP will provide more information.

Comment: I didn't VtC either, @r13. I try to give at least 24 hours for the person to come back... My comment was really targeted at the OP - that based on the info given, your comment is the best we can offer.

Comment: @FreeMan Got you. Thanks.